# How to calculate the derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{7}{(3x)^{-2}}\right]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone explain how to calculate the derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{7}{(3x)^{-2}}\right]$? The correct answer given was $126x$, however, I have gotten $42x$.

$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{7}{(3x)^{-2}}\right]=7\cdot(3x)^2=7\cdot2\cdot3x=42x$

Comment: You forgot Chain Rule (factor 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of $7\times(3x)^2=63x^2$ is $2\times63x=126x$.

As [imranfat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64546/imranfat) commented,

$\dfrac d {dx} \left[7\times u^2\right]=7\times2\times u\times\dfrac {du}{dx}=7\times2\times3x\times3$,

where $u=3x$.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the rule $$\frac{d}{dx}(\alpha x^\beta)=\alpha\beta x^{\beta -1}$$

and using this to conclude that $$\frac{d}{dx} (\alpha(ax)^\beta)=\alpha\beta(ax)^{\beta-1}$$

This is not true, indeed by the chain rule$$\frac{d([f(x)]^\beta)}{dx}=\frac{d[f(x)]}{dx}\cdot\frac{d([f(x)]^\beta)}{d[f(x)]}=f'(x)\cdot\beta(f(x))^{\beta-1}$$

(This might seem confusing, but set $u=f(x)$ and it looks more manageable.

Here $f(x)=ax\implies f'(x)=a$, so $$\frac{d}{dx} (\alpha(ax)^\beta)=a\alpha\beta(ax)^{\beta-1}$$ is correct.